# How to find largest cell values in multiple columns in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to figure out a formula to find the largest values of a column and then use the value of a second and third column basically to solve a tie, and then display the persons name associated to that data in a different cell.

I've provided an image with test data to try to illustrate what I need:

[image: Example Data]

To the right of the orange boxes shows the top 5 people based on the Criteria I want to use Basically I want Box 1 to display whatever person has the highest value in field K, followed by the second highest in box 2, etc. If the value in box K is identical I want the Value in the Total column to act as a tie breaker, if that still doesn't break the tie I want to use column I as the final tie breaker.

Obviously I want to leave the sorting in the table as is and the values within the table will change regularly (so copying all the data to a secondary data sheet manually to use sort functions won't work unless that process can be automated.) Any help would be appreciated. I've tried variations of VLOOKUP, INDEX, and MAX functions without any luck.

Comment: Assuming the values never exceed three digits, use a helper column, with value = K*10^6 + J*10^3 + I.  Then pick the top values from the helper column using the LARGE function.

Comment: You might be better off using VBA. You could then have a button that runs the macro with all the logic in it.

Comment: What is in the Orange boxes?

Comment: It's really challenging job,, now first tell  me how you are getting TOP FIVE NAME (what is the criteria) then it would easy to fix the issue!!

Comment: Your Sample data has few crucial issues. `1.` Name are unique `2.` Find Highest in `Col K`, return single value,, which is HIGHEST obvious. `3.` in this case **finding Second Highest is useless** since each name has only one Value in `K.` !! My suggestion is, to make the Question according to the Logics,, edit post and add Duplicate Name and related Values !!

Comment: Another,, if For any Name has, any highest values are identical, for example for `Cody suppose 2nd Highest is identical to 1st`,,  suppose are `110` and in this case if take support from `TOTAL col` which has suppose `480 & 525`,, then it doesn't makes any scene coz `both has same value in Col K i.e. 110`, therefore Formula return `110` ultimately !!

Answer (score 0):

Using a *criteria combining strategy* of weighting the most significant stats (@fixer1234), nets the following choices of formulas.

##### This formula will work when:

- A tie is impossible after the third criteria is applied.

  ```
  =INDEX( $C$2:$C$20, MATCH( LARGE( $K$2:$K$20*10^6+$J$2:$J$20*10^3+$I$2:$I$20, $B24), $K$2:$K$20*10^6+$J$2:$J$20*10^3+$I$2:$I$20, 0))
  ```
- The names are unique (or matching names do not also match on all 3 criteria).

  ```
  =INDEX( $C$2:$C$20, MATCH( LARGE( $K$2:$K$20*10^6+$J$2:$J$20*10^3+$I$2:$I$20, $B24), IF( NOT( COUNTIF( $D$23:$D23, $C$2:$C$20)), $K$2:$K$20*10^6+$J$2:$J$20*10^3+$I$2:$I$20, ""), 0))
  ```
- Always, by returning the results as user IDs (helper column starting at `E24`).

  ```
  =INDEX( $B$2:$B$20, MATCH( LARGE( $K$2:$K$20*10^6+$J$2:$J$20*10^3+$I$2:$I$20, $B24), IF( NOT( COUNTIF( $E$23:$E23, $B$2:$B$20)), $K$2:$K$20*10^6+$J$2:$J$20*10^3+$I$2:$I$20, ""), 0))
  ```
- For the name, use `=VLOOKUP($E24,$B$2:$C$20,2)` where `$E24` is the user id returned by the formula.

#### How to use

- Regardless of the main formula chosen, paste it to the first row of the results. These are CSE formulas so after entering the formula, or making changes, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Drag Copy the formula down. *These formulas do not return an array/range and will not work if entered as and array formula with all 5 cells selected.*
- Both `$E$23:$E23` in this formula and `$D$23:$D23` in the unique names formula; are expanding ranges that start in the cell above the first row of the formula. This first referenced cell of the expanding range must not match with any rows in the ids column or names column, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(SORTBY(A1:K20,K1:K20,-1,J1:J20,-1,I1:I20,-1),SORT(K1:K20,,-1)>=MIN(LARGE(K1:K20,SEQUENCE(5)))),SEQUENCE(5),2)
```

for the names and:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(SORTBY(A1:K20,K1:K20,-1,J1:J20,-1,I1:I20,-1),SORT(K1:K20,,-1)>=MIN(LARGE(K1:K20,SEQUENCE(5)))),SEQUENCE(5),11)
```

for the scores in column K.

Sort the data formulaically using `SORTBY()` and use that sorted set of data for `FILTER()`'s input range. This sets the data up for following your tiebreakers without any actual effort plus, oddly (every weird thing with `FILTER()` gets "oddly" as a descriptor), using `MIN()` won't work out (as I've written it) without the setup sort. So that's why the `SORTBY()` before passing the range of data to `FILTER()`.

For the criteria in the `FILTER()` function to work, the criteria range must be sorted as well, before then being set `>=` to the five largest column K results.

For some reason, one I did not invest too much time in figuring out, but rather in overcoming, directly comparing the column K scores to the five largest column K values did not work. But using `LARGE()` to FIND the highest five, then `MIN()` to select the lowest of those, and THEN comparing the sorted column K values as `FILTER()`'s criterium did work. So you see.

That produced, internally in Excel, not as a result, a table of the table values in the desired order and cut off to be five rows. Using `INDEX()` allowed the selection of the column of interest, column 2 to get the names, and column 11 to get the column K scores. Hence the two formulas, differing only by the column at their ends which is passed to `INDEX()`, to get the names for one column of your output table and the column K scores for the other.

Bear in mind that if someone else matched Joe in all three columns, if that person were above Joe in the source range, he would have been in position 5 and Joe would have been in position 6. And vice versa if he had been below Joe in the source range. The formula does not handle that in any way and I mean AT ALL.

It does, however, do what is literally requested.

This also shows that one need not solve difficulties in the sense of then being able to do what was tried. One may often simply overcome then and move on without ever knowing what would have made the logical approach work. I do always like to solve each thing, but it's a practical world and working output usually is more desirable than perfect output at the cost of a ton of time. So one fairly often has to compromise and put off understanding for another day. Which works so...